# How to RE-set a setData variable within a view?

Tags: magento, variables, view

How do I reset a setData variable within a view?

**Example:**
view.phtml:

```
$this->getChild('additional')->setData('foo', 'Bar'); 


if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
       <?php echo $html ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;
```

attributes.phtml

```
echo $this->getData('foo'); // returns: Bar
```

When I am trying to set the data again but with another value (within view.phtml)
like:

view.phtml:

```
$this->getChild('additional')->setData('foo', 'Second'); 


if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
    <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
       <?php echo $html ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;
```

attributes.phtml

```
echo $this->getData('foo'); // it still returns: Bar
```

How do I update this variable *foo*?

Thanks,

Martijn

Comment: You could try unsetData('foo')

Comment: @nevermourn unfortunately that doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You're reseting well the variable, but you have to disable the cache of the block.

Remove the cache informations of the _construct function of your cache Block. From this:

```
protected function _construct()
{
$this->addData(array(
‘cache_lifetime’=> false,
‘cache_tags’ => array(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG, Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG)
));
}
```

To this:

```
protected function _construct() {}
```